# drupal modules not listing

Tags: php, drupal

Have issues on Module listing in Production server

when i add new modules in production website. it doesn't shown up the modules in list. So take a copy and change the mysql values on settings.php local machine. when it executes it shows the added modules in list.

Before this post am take some debugging measures which are:-

check 755 permission for sites/all/module - correct
module version checking - correct.
local and production website cleared the cache table.

If any one can help me to solve this issue.

Comment: is there the .info file and syntax is correct ?

Comment: Am check with Popular views module. it also not listed

Answer (score 0):

In page `admin/user/permissions` do you find that the 'administer modulename' permission for each module is assigned to the admin user?